# InfoWindows are opening Without Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am using googlemaps api to put some marker on maps. However for some reason my infoWindows for all marker, get opened by default  Even when there is no click. I am not sure why this is happening, I tried searching elsewhere the below code looks to be ok (atleast to me)

```
function PoplatePoints(data) {
var output = new google.maps.LatLng(25.4486, 78.5696);
var mapOptions = {
  center: output,
  zoom: 7
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

//var contentString = [];
//  var infowindow = [];
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  var contentString = 'Hello This is me';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var  icon_new = "/static/beyond/img/Green.png";

  var marker = new  google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].long),
    map: map,
    icon: icon_new
  });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(mm,tt) {
     infowindow.setContent(tt)
     infowindow.open(map, mm)
   })(marker, contentString));
}
```

}

Comment: because you are immediately executing your click callback function instead of passing a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code at the very end that sets up the click handler. It is trying to set up a closure in a fancy way, but it's inadvertently using an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). Note the "Immediately Invoked" part of that. The code isn't passing a function *reference* to `addEventListener` as it should, it's actually *executing* the function first.

You do want a closure here, but there is a much simpler way to set it up. I would do it like this:

```
function PopulatePoints( data ) {
    var output = new google.maps.LatLng( 25.4486, 78.5696 );
    var mapOptions = {
        center: output,
        zoom: 7
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions
    );

    for( var i = 0;  i < data.length;  ++i ) {
        AddPoint( data[i] );
    }

    function addPoint( point ) {
        // TODO: This string will probably be passed in as a
        // property of the point variable
        var contentString = 'Hello This is me';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var icon_new = "/static/beyond/img/Green.png";

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( point.lat, point.long ),
            map: map,
            icon: icon_new
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent( marker );
            infowindow.open( map, contentString );
        });
    }
}
```